# How can I hide an rdlc report Tablix based on the contents of cells in a column, in Sql Server Report Services?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have the following table in a report:

[image]

I need to hide the table (or even better, add some message that this has happened) for when all of the value cells pictured have no value. So in the picture example, the table would not be hidden, but if the 5 values were missing, it would be.

The problem is there's no real way to reference cells, or even columns in SSRS as far as I can tell via Google. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this type of thing is to check the row count of the underlying data set for the tablix. If it is not zero, then show the tablix. This is what the expression would look something like in the Hidden property for the tablix.

```
=IIf(CountRows("DataSet1") <> 0, False, True)
```

Add a label that says something like "No data to report" to the report that only shows when the dataset is empty. Expression here:

```
=IIf(CountRows("DataSet1") = 0, False, True)
```

This assumes that no records will be returned in the dataset when there are no values for all selected columns. This also assumes that the name of your dataset is DataSet1.

EDIT:

Another possible approach is to check all of the dataset values that fill the cells, if they are all empty, then hide the tablix. Something like this could be used for the Hidden property:

```
=IIf(Fields!field_name1.Value <> "" OR Fields!field_name2.Value <> "" (etc.), False, True)
```

One other approach is to check for values in the SQL for the dataset. If all of the values are empty return an extra column, maybe named hidden, that is false. True if values are present. Not the prettiest approach, and it may mean a significant change to your SQL, but it could work.

With this last one, instead of returning true or false, you could return a 1 or 0. Then, in the RDL for the Hidden property, sum that column and if it is = 0, hide the tablix.

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!hidden.Value, "DataSet1") <> 0, False, True)
```

Comment: I've tried using CountRows(), CountRows("DataSet1") and CountRows("Tablix1") and I get the value 1 returned every time. I'm not sure why in the above example, when I can see I have 7 rows. But that doesn't matter either, in my question I'm meaning the cells in the column and whether they are blank. The whole row will still exist even if there's no value in the cell of that 2nd column.

Comment: I have added some other possible solutions to my answer

Comment: Yeah, the long Or Statement Chain did cross my mind. I'm that XDocument guy from the other day by the way. I may have to consider that approach again.

Comment: I was sort of leaning toward that last one where you sum the hidden field. That would work with an unlimited number of records. If I recall, this tablix has a ton of rows. I do remember you. Again, good luck!

Comment: I like that approach. One thing I'm noticing is I've got a single field name with a single value for each of my rows. But most rdlc reports don't seem to be set up this way. The hidden field you mention seems to be a column with n cells in it. How do you create a column in this way? All I see is the option to insert a blank column to the right of my existing table above, with no values in it. I should also add that I'm using Visual Studio to design these reports.

Comment: No need to create a new column in the RDL, just have the new column of data come from the datasets SQL. You don't have to show it. You just need to have it available in the dataset so you can show/hide the tablix based on the value(s) it returns. If you are not the one who wrote the SQL, you may want to get with whomever did. Since this is RDLC, someone may have to change something else, too. Like the object you use for data.